# Urn Probability Combination Problem

Tags: probability, computer-science

I am in my first year of Comp Sci and I am reviewing for my Math Final.

There are two Urns $U_1$ and $U_2$. $U_1$ has $10$ red balls and $8$ blue balls. $U_2$ has $16$ red and $4$ blue. Suppose you choose one of the two urns at random pick two balls without replacement.

1. What is the probability that two red balls are selected?
2. What is the probability the balls picked have different color
3. Suppose the balls were put into one urn would the probability of choosing two red balls (without replacement) be higher?

I have done simpler versions of this question but not with indistinct balls. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to MSE if you could mention what you have done (like what you did with simpler versions) that would be good.

Comment: Assume you pick $U_1$.  Can you find the chance of getting a red ball the first time?  Assuming you do, how many balls of each color are left?  What is the chance you get a red ball for the second draw? What does that make the chance you get two red balls in a row out of $U_1$?

Comment: The simpler version it two urns U1 and U2 U1 has 3 red balls R1 R2 R3 and 2 blue balls B1 B2. Urn two has 2 red balls R1 and R2 and 3 green balls G1 G2 G3. What is probability of getting two red balls? Thats what I have done before and that one is easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let's look at the following hypotheses: $H_1$: $U_1$ was picked, $H_2$: $U_2$ was picked. By the problem's definition, $\mathrm{P}(H_1) = \mathrm{P}(H_2) = \frac12$.
   Let $R$ denote the event that two red balls were chosen.
   Now, observe that $\displaystyle \mathrm{P}(R \mid H_1) = \frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{18}{2}}$ and $\displaystyle \mathrm{P}(R \mid H_2) = \frac{\binom{16}{2}}{\binom{20}{2}}$. Now, by the formula for [total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), we have that $\mathrm{P}(R) = \mathrm{P}(R \mid H_1) \mathrm{P}(H_1) + \mathrm{P}(R \mid H_2) \mathrm{P}(H_2) = \ldots$;
2. As previously, let $R$ denote the event that two red balls were chosen, and $B$ the event that two black balls where chosen. Now, the probability that the two balls are of different color is $1 - \mathrm{P}(R) - \mathrm{P}(B)$;
3. I think you can handle this one yourself.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Now for 3 would it be 26choose2/38choose2, just to make sure I am on the right track. Also I don't know how to do the fancy formatting, sorry.

Comment: @stalindroid: Indeed.